# Format string with special character

Tags: python, string, special-characters

I have some string with special characters, and i want to remove these characters.

```
def clean_special(input: str):  # This function is my cleaner
    # Idk how change these '.replace()' to something more efficient
    cleaning = re.sub(r'[()&.-]', ' ', input).replace("’", '')
    cleaning = cleaning.replace(',', '').replace("'", '').replace("[", '').replace("]", '').strip()
    return " ".join(cleaning.split())


original_string = 'Sabai, With Løve & Nevve - Falling For You (Official Music Video)'  # Title of music, with some special characters
cleaned_string = clean_special(original_string)
print(f'{original_string=}\n{cleaned_string=}')
```

It works, but when i have special characters like `「Future Core」...` just breaks

So i tryied other way:

```
string = '「Future Core」[lapix] Carry Me Away (Extended Mix)'

print(''.join(i for i in string if i.isalnum()))
```

And works, but now have a joined string, i wanted something like `Future Core lapix Carry Me Away Extended Mix` with spaces like the first attempt.

Someone can help me? ;-

> I need these returns from code: `Sabai With Løve Nevve Falling For You Official Music Video` and `Future Core lapix Carry Me Away Extended Mix`

Comment: `''.join(i for i in string if i.isalnum() or i.isspace())` ?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', string)`

Comment: Tks guys <333333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved code

```
string = '「Future Core」[lapix] Carry Me Away (Extended Mix)'

print(''.join(i for i in string if i.isalnum() or i.isspace()))
```

## or

```
def clean_special(input: str):
    cleaning = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+', '', input)
    return " ".join(cleaning.split())


string = '「Future Core」[lapix] Carry Me Away (Extended Mix)'
print(clean_special(string))
```

Comment: Note: the regex solution will convert `Løve` to `Lve`. You could try `cleaning = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]+', '', input)`